# Running label_image.py in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

My goal is to continuously classify .jpg images coming from a video stream.

To do so I have just modified the [label_image.py example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py).

I'm loading the graph and opening the sessions beforehand. Then I'm only running the following code in a loop :

```
t = read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                                input_height=input_height,
                                input_width=input_width,
                                input_mean=input_mean,
                                input_std=input_std)


input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

results = sess2.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                  {input_operation.outputs[0]: t}
                  )

results = np.squeeze(results)

top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
labels = load_labels(label_file)
```

It works well for a few minutes but the problem is that every cycle the classification slows down progressively. It goes from half a second to a few seconds in one minute. 
My memory usage is also going up slowly, about a 1 MB increase every 3 seconds.

If I classify a single image multiple times, leaving out the "read_tensor_from_image_file", I don't get this bug.

So something in the image loading code must be taking up more space every time, not clearing up properly :

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name, input_height=192, input_width=192,
                                input_mean=0, input_std=255):
  input_name = "file_reader"
  output_name = "normalized"
  file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
  if file_name.endswith(".png"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                       name='png_reader')
  elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
    image_reader = tf.squeeze(tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader,
                                                  name='gif_reader'))
  elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name='bmp_reader')
  else:
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                        name='jpeg_reader')
  float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
  dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
  resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height, input_width])
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])

  result = sess1.run(normalized)


  return result
```

Every suggestion is very much appreciated, I'm totally stuck on this one.

I'm using python 3.4.2 with tensorflow 1.1.0 on a raspberry pi with raspbian jessie.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call read_tensor_from_image_file, it would create a lot of new nodes in the TensorFlow graph. As you said, this function is called in a loop in your code, so it would dynamically create a lot of new graph nodes in every iteration. This might be the reason of memory usage increase and slowness.

A better way is to create the graph once, and then just run the graph in your loop. For example, you can modify your `read_tensor_from_image_file` as follows:

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(input_height=192, input_width=192, input_mean=0, input_std=255):
  input_name = "file_reader"
  output_name = "normalized"

  # [NEW] make file_name as a placeholder.
  file_name = tf.placeholder("string", name="fname")

  file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
  ...
  normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), [input_std])

  # [NEW] don't call sess1 when building graph.
  # result = sess1.run(normalized)    
  # return result
  return normalized
```

In your server, you only invoke `read_tensor_from_image_file` once, and save it as `read_tensor_from_image_file_op =read_tensor_from_image_file(...)` somewhere.

In your loop, you can simply call:

```
t = sess2.run(read_tensor_from_image_file_op, feed_dict={"fname:0": file_name})

input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);
results = sess2.run(output_operation.outputs[0],
                  {input_operation.outputs[0]: t}
                  )
results = np.squeeze(results)

top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
labels = load_labels(label_file)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! You really saved my day. If anyone tries to replicate it, you just have to change   feed_dict={"fname": file_name} to   feed_dict={"fname:0": file_name}